# ReactJS and D3JS: setState

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to visualize a stock price chart, using reactJS and D3JS(v5).

- Fetching data from Alphavantage API
- Framework = ReactJS (which, honestly, introduces an unnecessary layer of complexity)
- D3JS for viz

Roughly three parts to this:

1. global function `parseData()`. Parses data from the `fetch` into a
   format that d3 can read. Verified working, but included for
   completeness.
2. `componentDidMount()` call within `class App`. Promise chain: has fetch call, then `parseData()`, then `setState()`, and finally
   `drawChart()`
3. `drawChart()` local function within `class App`: contains all D3 logic. Will be separated out into its own component later. Works if I pass it data from a local json (commented out; some sample rows provided below), but not when I try to pass it
   data from `fetch`.

Code so far: this is all in `App.js`, no child components:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import * as d3 from "d3";
//import testTimeData from "./data/testTimeData"

function parseData(myInput) {
  // processes alpha vantage data into a format for viz
  // output an array of objects, 
  // where each object is {"Date":"yyyy-mm-dd", "a":<float>}
  let newArray = []
  for (var key in myInput) {
      if (myInput.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          const newRow = Object.assign({"newDate": new Date(key)}, {"Date": key}, myInput[key])
          newArray.push(newRow)
      }
  }
  //console.log(newArray)
  // 2. Generate plotData for d3js
  let newArray2 = []
  for (var i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++) {
    let newRow = Object.assign({"Date": newArray[i]["Date"]}, {"a":parseFloat(newArray[i]["4. close"])})
    newArray2.unshift(newRow)
  }

  return newArray2
}


class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      ticker:"", 
      plotData:[]
    }
    this.drawChart = this.drawChart.bind(this)
  }

  // setState() in componentDidMount()
  // fetch monthly data
  // hardcode ticker = VTSAX for the moment
  // and call this.drawChart()
  componentDidMount() {
    const ticker = "VTSAX"
    const api_key = "EEKL6B77HNZE6EB4"
    fetch("https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_MONTHLY&symbol="+ticker+"&apikey="+api_key)
    .then(console.log("fetching..."))
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => parseData(data["Monthly Time Series"]))
    .then(data => console.log(data))
    .then(data =>{this.setState({plotData:data, ticker:ticker})})
    .then(this.drawChart());
  }


  drawChart() {
    const stockPlotData = this.state.plotData
    console.log("stockPlotData.length=", stockPlotData.length)
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", 960)
      .attr("height", 300)

    var margin = {left:50, right:30, top:30, bottom: 30}
    var width = svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right;
    var height = svg.attr("height") - margin.bottom - margin.top;

    var x = d3.scaleTime().rangeRound([0, width]);
    var y = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([height, 0]);
    var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");

    x.domain(d3.extent(stockPlotData, function(d) { return parseTime(d.date); }));
    y.domain([0, 
              d3.max(stockPlotData, function(d) { 
                return d.a;
              })]);

    var multiline = function(category) {
      var line = d3.line()
                  .x(function(d) { return x(parseTime(d.date)); })
                  .y(function(d) { return y(d[category]); });
      return line;
    }

    var g = svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform",
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var categories = ['a'];
    for (let i in categories) {
      var lineFunction = multiline(categories[i]);
      g.append("path")
        .datum(stockPlotData) 
        .attr("class", "line")
        .style("stroke", "blue")
        //.style("stroke", color(i))
        .style("fill", "None")
        .attr("d", lineFunction);
    }

    // append X Axis
    g.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%Y-%m-%d")));

    // append Y Axis
    g.append("g")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
  }

  render(){
    return (<div>{this.state.ticker}</div>)
  }
}


export default App;
```

Outputs from `console.log()` calls:

- `data => console.log(data)` within the promise chain of `componentDidMount()` correctly displays the fetched data
- But `console.log("stockPlotData.length=", stockPlotData.length)` call in the `drawChart()` function returns `stockPlotData.length= 0`. Did I call `this.setState()` wrongly?
- The page renders "VTSAX" correctly in the `render(){return(...)}` call at the bottom, indicating that `this.setState` updated the `ticker` variable correctly.

Some test data rows:

```
[
{"Date":"2016-01-15", "a": 220 },
{"Date":"2016-01-16", "a": 250},
{"Date":"2016-01-17", "a": 130},
{"Date":"2016-01-18", "a": 180},
{"Date":"2016-01-19", "a": 200},
]
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a lot of code to read, but based on a quick glance, you probably want to call this.drawChart() inside of a .then instead of after your promise chain, because it's gonna fire before your promises resolve.

Comment: Edited and tested, but no change in the output.

Comment: Doesn't the last .then need a function as its first argument? I think based on what I'm seeing in your edit you immediately call drawChart still. Can you try .then(data => this.drawChart());

Comment: Isn't `this.drawChart()` a function already? I tried your suggestion anyway; returned a very unusual error "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'length' of undefined", and highlighted the line `var margin = {left:50...`.